# How to link esp32 push button action to a button in a react native app?

Tags: firebase, react-native, arduino, esp32

I have a react native app with a button that does some action, and on the other hand I have a small device with esp32 and a push button. The esp32 device is already linked by Bluetooth Low Energy to the mobile app, what I want to do is : when the push button is clicked, it launches the action of the mobile app button .
(My app is developed in react native and firebase)

Comment: Your question can be more clear. From my understanding you are asking a code sample for both esp32 and react native which pressing on physical push button lets esp32 to transmit ble signal to mobile phone and trigger a function which is written in react native right?

Comment: @MehmetFiliz Yess exactly like that

Answer (score 0):

ESP32 code
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZi7ykalZhc

React Native
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ble-connect

First write down the code from youtube run and test if its connecting the nRF app
Then use the "react-native-ble-connect" library to connect and trigger any function you want